# jquery Tab only works when referring the script locally in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to use jquery UI tab in mvc4 application. All the necessary scripts and styles added in bundleconfig and referred in layout.cshtml page.

please refer below code.

```
<div id="tabs">     
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Table</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Heat</a></li>       
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
 content fo tab1
</div>     
<div id="tabs-2">
Content for Tab2
</div>  
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(function () { 
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });    
</script>
```

**required scripts already referred in layout.cshtml. but still tab not working properly. then i tried to add it in locally in same .cshtml page.**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.9.0.css")" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then it works fine but it loaded jquery and UI scripts two times

[image]

I don't know what the exact problem is.

Comment: what is the repeating id ?

Comment: Misread the ID's -- no repeating, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Hey try as follow and remove the added jquery lib files from .cshtml page.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs").tabs();
 });
```

Comment: already tried to use document.ready but not works same problem.

Comment: try this thing move script block before the  "<div id='tabs'>"          <script type="text/javascript">    
    $(function () { 
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });    
</script>

Comment: or remove  the function wrappper like this <script type="text/javascript">    
         $("#tabs").tabs();  
</script>

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add render section for scripts to the end of body tag in layout.cshtml

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

And type script code in Scripts section on view

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
    </script>
}
```

PS: links for jquery and jquery.ui must be before RenderSection in layout.cshtml